# When to use Hamiltonian vs Lagrangian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

I currently studying the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalisms in classical mechanics, but something I'm not seeing is how do I know which one to use in a given problem?  After I find the Lagrangian, should I just try the Euler equation and if that doesn't look nice try the Hamiltonian?  Or are there some hallmarks of different problems that could indicate whether one would be easier than the other?  And while we're at it, how do I know that I should use the Newtonian approach (other than if the problem involves friction)?

Comment: Related: (read all answers) http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89035/

Comment: Y'know, the purpose of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics is not to merely solve problems - we could've stayed with Newton for that.