# Conceptual difference between Hamiltonian and Lagrangian formulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

What is the basic difference between Lagrangian formulation and Hamiltonian formulations of mechanics? Why do we have two formulations when we can work with Hamiltonian most of the times (in quantum mechanics). I want to know a more conceptual answer rather than just the formulas.

Comment: I fixed the title. Please read our [FAQ on writing good titles](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89035/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21866/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44722/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174818/2451 and links therein.