# What is the purpose of phase space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Why is phase space important? As far as I'm concerned, you're just rewriting the dynamic law using momentum instead of velocity and mass. $$m \space \frac {d \ \vec v}{d\ t}=\vec F \\ \frac{d \ \vec r}{d \ t} = \vec v$$ Changed to $$ \frac {d \ \vec p} {d \ t} = \vec F \\ \frac {d \ \vec r}{d \ t} = \frac  {\vec p}{m}$$

Comment: Liouville’s theorem      https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)   and canonical transformations   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation  come to mind

Comment: It is  a formulation  consistent with special relativity vectors

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89035/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

[Define phase space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space):

> In mathematics and physics, a phase space of a dynamical system is a space in which all possible states of a system are represented, with each possible state corresponding to one unique point in the phase space. For mechanical systems, the phase space usually consists of all possible values of position and momentum variables.

So you mean why chose momentum and position? For conceptual and mathematical simplicity. In addition this carries over when special relativity is included with its four vectors ${(t,x,y,z)}$ and ${(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)}$