# Lagrangian is there so why we need hamiltonian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

We know lagrangian L(q,v)=T-V,
and Hamilton is H(p,q)=T+V,
why we need Hamiltonian , isn't Lagrangian enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the point of Hamiltonian mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89035/)