What is the benefit of Hamiltonian formalism to promote ($q,\dot{q},t$) from Lagrangian to ($q,p,t$) despite getting the same EOM finally?
Hamiltonian formalism follows
$$H(q,p,t)=\sum_i\dot{q_i}p_i-L(q_i,\dot{q}_i,t) $$ and $$\dot{p}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}, \dot{q}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p} $$
but finally these will get the same equation of motion as Lagrangian formalism. What is the {point, advantage, benefit, etc.} for using (q,p,t) variables in Hamiltonian formalism while we can get EOM from Lagrangian formalism?, and we have to get the Lagrangian $L$ first to get Hamiltonian $H$.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89035/2451 and links therein.


First of all, Hamilton's equations are 2n first order differential equations, whereas Euler-Lagrange equations are n second order differential equations, which can make them harder to solve.*

Secondly, switching from $\{q,\dot{q},t\}$ space to $\{q,p,t\}$ space allows for cannonical transformations which are a coordinate change from $\{q,p,t\}$ to $\{Q(q,p),P(q,p),t\}$ in which the equations can be easier to solve.

The fact that there are two first order differential equation guaranties that paths in the $\{q,p\}$ space do not intersect which is essential for the Liouville theorem (and thus statistical mechanics).

The $\{p,q,t\}$ coordinate space allows for the Poisson bracket formalism.

The Hamiltonian is the generator of time translations, and as such allows for a treatment of conserved quantites. This makes the Hamiltonian more fundamental than the Lagrangian.

The Hamiltonian is essential for the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism which allows to find conserved quantities (and use them to solve the equations of motion).


*Edit: 2n first order differential equations are not easier to solve.

Prior to modern methods, Lagrangian 2nd order equations are often easier to solve. That is why Routhians exist: to take the conserved quantities from Hamiltonians as much as we can find, and then return back to Lagrangian 2nd order equations for the parts that we have no choice but to do numerical integration.

Every system of N second-order odes is equivalent to a system of 2N first-order equations. Therefore, the argument about Lagrange equations being harder to solve than Hamilton equations has no basis.

Thank you, clear picture.
