# What is the physical meaning of the minus sign in the Hamilton equation of momenta?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

The Hamilton equations are

$$ \dot{q}_k=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_k}~~~~-\dot{p}_k=\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_k}~~~~~-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}.$$

Does the minus sign of the momenta equation, have a physical meaning?

Comment: The long and short answer is symplectic geometry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the Hamiltonian for a single particle in some potential
$$H(p,q) = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(q)$$
where the first term is the kinetic energy and the second term is the potential energy. In this case, we have
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial q}$$
On the other hand, the momentum is
$$p = mv$$
where $m$ is the mass and $v$ is the velocity, so
$$\dot{p} = \frac{d}{dt}{m v} = m\dot{v} = m a$$
where $a$ is the acceleration. In this case, the Hamilton equation
$$-\dot{p} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}$$
becomes
$$-m a = \frac{\partial V}{\partial q}$$
If we now use Newton's second law
$$F = ma,$$
we get $$F = - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q}$$
If we didn't have the minus sign in the Hamilton equation, we wouldn't have the minus sign here. It tells you that the Force associated with a potential always acts in the direction which makes it smaller. (If $\partial V/\partial q$ is positive, that means $V$ gets larger when $q$ becomes larger, so $F$ acts in the opposite direction.)

This is why things fall down. Because the gravitational potential gets lower in that direction. If the minus sign wasn't there, everything would fall up instead of down. So it's pretty important in keeping the universe together.

Comment: Thank you very much!!.  I thought that it was something more tricky and did not realize that taking into account an example would give me the answer.

Comment: So the physical meaning is basically that the universe does not explode ;-). I feel sad for the universes which were missing this little detail. R.I.P.

Answer (score 7):

More broadly speaking, the asymmetric minus sign in [Hamilton's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) is intimately related to the antisymmetry of the [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry)/[Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold) structure, which in turn has several consequences, e.g.

1. [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)), i.e. that [Hamiltonian vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) are divergence-free.
2. An [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) Hamiltonian is an [integral of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion).

For more informations, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32738/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133952/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136182/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88920/2451) related Phys.SE posts.